# Как найти координаты click'а?

Tags: javascript, svg

Работаю с svg.

Надо найти координаты клика на svg.

Получаю координаты так:

```
$('svg').mousedown(function(e) {
    var x = e.originalEvent.layerX,
        y = e.originalEvent.layerY;
    ...
```

Проблема в том, что на svg присутствуют image, а работа с ними отличается в FF и Chrome. При клике на image:

- Chrome считает layerX от начала svg
- FF считает LayerX от начала image

как получить координаты от начала svg в обоих случаях?

Comment: var position = $paper.offset();

Comment: @L.Vadim, спасибо. А $paper это кто? дайте ссылку

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132758/cross-browser-solution-for-replacing-the-use-of-event-layerx-and-event-layery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0n77tpm0/ если вычитать координаты `getBoundingClientRect`, то вроде всё одинаково в фф и хроме.

Comment: Вопросы в вопросы, ответы в ответы.

Answer (score 3):

`e.clientX` и `e.clientY`.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
  y = e.clientY;
  
  alert("x: " + x + " y:" + y);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #afb7f0;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200">
    <image id="image" xlink:href="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" x="20" y="20" height="32px" width="45px" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но клик висит не на image, а на svg. getBoundingClientRect не дает желаемого: http://jsfiddle.net/0n77tpm0/2/

Comment: заменил image на svg, проверил в фф и хроме, по-прежнему результат работы скрипта одинаковый.

Comment: сравните, координаты клика на image и рядом но на svg jsfiddle.net/0n77tpm0/2

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kdw54vh4/ а так?

Comment: так заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Правильно оказалось так:

```
$('svg').mousedown(function(e) {
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg'),
        bcr = svg.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clienX - bcr.left,
        y = e.clientY - bcr.top;
    ...
```